# Отправка email через php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Имеется форма

```
    <div class="form-box">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p class="form-message-truee">Спасибо. Заявка отправлена</p>
        <form method="post" class="feedbackForm-scs" action="#" id="feedbackForm1">
            <div class="form">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                    <label>Ваше Имя*</label>
                    <input type="text" class="name-input" name="namephone" required id="name-input-feedback-footer">
                    <span class="error-field" id="name-error-feedback-footer"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                    <label>Email*</label>
                    <input type="phone" class="phone-input" name="telphone" required id="phone-input-feedback-footer">

                    <span class="error-field" id="phone-error-feedback-footer"></span>
                </div>
                <button class="button-submit" type="submit" class="btbtw1">Уведомить о поступлении</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Со скриптом

```
<script>
jQuery('#feedbackForm1').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var namephone = jQuery('#namephone').val();
    var telphone = jQuery('#telphone').val('none');
    var ref = document.referrer;

    if (telphone != '') {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "email.php",
            data: jQuery('form#feedbackForm1').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                jQuery('.feedbackForm-scs').css('opacity', 0);
                jQuery('.sent-ok').css('opacity', 0);
                jQuery('.feedbackForm-sc-old').fadeIn(250);
                jQuery('.form-message-truee').fadeIn(250);
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('Error. Not send.');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

и PHP обработчиком

```
<?php
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset = utf-8' . "\r\n";


  if (!empty($_POST['namefr']))
    {
      mail('mail@mail.ru', 'Поступил предзаказ товара с ', $mes3, $headers);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['namephone'])) { $namephone= $_POST['namephone']; }
    if(isset($_POST['ref'])) { $ref= $_POST['ref']; }
    if(isset($_POST['telphone'])) { $telphone= $_POST['telphone']; }

    $mes2 = "Поступил предзаказ товара <br> 
    Со страницы: $ref<br> 
    Имя клиента: $namephone <br>  
    Телефон: $telphone<br> ";

    $mes2 = wordwrap($mes2, 200);
  $sub2 = "Поступил предзаказ товара";
  if (!empty($_POST['telphone']))
    {
      mail('mail@mail.ru', $sub2, $mes2, $headers);
    }
?>
```

Проблема в чем, пытаюсь задать переменной реферальную ссылку document.referrer , и отправить ее в POST. Но зараза нечего не получается. Поля мыла и телефона все ок, а рефа не хочет

Comment: не видно, чтобы var ref = document.referrer; далее участвовал в отправке формы. самое простое, добавьте в форму hidden поле id="ref", name="ref" и устанавливайте его значение согласно реферу: jQuery('#ref').val(document.referrer);

Comment: Спасибо большое, прокатило